# Android Studio hover highlight objects

Tags: android, xml, hover, android-linearlayout, highlight

In android studio is there a way to highlight objects when the mouse is hovering?  A way that doesn't involve different images?  Like if I wanted to highlight a linearlayout with XML?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings -> Editor.
In the column "Highlight on Caret Movement, check "Highligh usage of element on caret".
You could see it here:

[image]

In addition you could adust the color of the highlight background.
File->Settings -> Editor - > Colors & Fonts - > General . Then find "Identifier under caret and pick the desired Background color. You should select custom theme to change the value.

[image]